# Adding a dynamic physic body to a drawn line

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, jbox2d

I'm developing a game with a similar mechanical to "Crayon Physics Deluxe" on libGDX (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avkacGQKWec). I'm stuck on the algorithm implementation of the drawn. The problem is that dynamics bodies doesn't work with EdgeShapes and ChainShapes. I've attempted using a polygonization algorithm, but it doesn't work exactly like "Crayon Physics" and creates a lot of bugs.

Is there any way to adding a dynamic body to the drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've solved the problem concatenating rectangles. The method is detailed below. The process has 3 parts:

**1.- Reduction of user input**

For improve the performance, I've defined a tolerance distance: Every point has to be separated from previous by the tolerance distance defined.

**2.- Smoothing input**

For avoiding peaks and jagged corners I've used one iteration of Chaikin's smoothing algorithm.(http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu/education/CAGDNotes/Chaikins-Algorithm/Chaikins-Algorithm.html)

**3.- Build a line of rectangles**

Once we have the input processed and smoothed, the last step is build de physic body. That body will have a multiple rectangle
fixtures. Concretly, *NUMBER_OF_POINTS/2* fixtures, since we'll construct a rectangle every two points. The next draw illustrate the process:

[Drawing of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cavGV.png)

And that's the code to achive it:

```
private static Body createPhysicBodies(Array<Vector2> input, World world) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size - 1; i++) {
        Vector2 point = input.get(i);
        Vector2 dir = input.get(i + 1).cpy().sub(point);
        float distance = dir.len();
        float angle = dir.angle() * MathUtils.degreesToRadians;
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();    
        shape.setAsBox(distance / 2, Constants.THICKNESS / 2, dir.cpy()
                .scl(0.5f).add(point), angle);
        body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);
    }
    return body;
}
```